# Is it ok to say higer order functions (map, filter ...) achieve polymorphism?

Tags: types, functional-programming, polymorphism, computer-science, higher-order-functions

```
map(array, f)
```

I thought higher order functions are polymorphic. Since that operates in many ways. But when I have searched about polymorphism, there was no such thing like 'anonymous functions or higher order functions are polymorphic'.

Although the variable f does various operations and the f is an interface which takes each value in an array as a parameter, It's not polymorphic?

Is it only about types?

I thought like something operates in various ways is polymorphic. like function overloading in C++

Is it wrong to say like that in CS ?

In my view, subtype polymorphism is quite similar with higher order functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this lovely [parable of Anton van Straaten's](https://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg03277.html) that likens objects to closures.

## Functions

Consider a function. Let's make it concrete and say that it receives a string and returns an integer. (It might, for example, count the number of letters in the string.) In Haskell, such a function might have the type `String -> Int`.

If you have a higher-order function like the typical [functor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/22/functors) map (as I assume the OP function represents), you can use *any* `String -> Int` function to map a collection of strings to a collection of integers:

```
ghci> map length ["foo", "bar", "b", "az"]
[3,3,1,2]
```

You could also write another function with the same type. Let's say, for example, that you wanted to count all the occurrences of a particular character in a string.

```
ghci> countOccurencesOf ch = length . filter ((==) ch)
ghci> countOccurencesOf 'a' "bar"
1
ghci> countOccurencesOf 'a' "bara"
2
ghci> countOccurencesOf 'b' "bara"
1
```

This function takes two inputs: a character and a string, but if you partially apply it, you create a new function that takes only a string. This is very similar to a closure.

Such a closure can also be used with the same `map` function:

```
ghci> map (countOccurencesOf 'r') ["foo", "bar", "brr"]
[0,1,2]
```

Thus, it seems reasonable to consider the function input into `map` as being polymorphic.

## Objects

Since [objects are isomorphic to closures](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/02/12/object-isomorphisms), we can demonstrate the same idea using objects.

Imagine that we have a mapper over collections. I'll now use C#.

Keeping it concrete, imagine that we define a function that only maps collections of string to collections of integers:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Map(IEnumerable<string> source, StringToIntMapping mapping)
{
    var result = new List<int>();
    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        result.Add(mapping.Map(s));
    }
    return result;
}
```

where `StringToIntMapping` is an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class StringToIntMapping
{
    public abstract int Map(string s);
}
```

You can now repeat the same examples as above by passing polymorphic objects to the `Map` function. Here, the examples are given as unit tests:

```
[Fact]
public void CountLetters()
{
    var collection = new[] { "foo", "bar", "b", "az" };
    var actual = Map(collection, new CountLettersMapping());
    Assert.Equal(new[] { 3, 3, 1, 2 }, actual);
}

[Fact]
public void CountOccurences()
{
    var collection = new[] { "foo", "bar", "brr" };
    var actual = Map(collection, new CountOccurencesMapping('r'));
    Assert.Equal(new[] { 0, 1, 2 }, actual);
}
```

The two polymorphic objects used here are two derived classes:

```
public sealed class CountLettersMapping : StringToIntMapping
{
    public override int Map(string s)
    {
        return s.Length;
    }
}

public sealed class CountOccurencesMapping : StringToIntMapping
{
    private readonly char c;

    public CountOccurencesMapping(char c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public override int Map(string s)
    {
        return s.Count(x => x == c);
    }
}
```

You could now introduce generics to support mapping of any two types:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Map<T, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Mapping<T, TResult> mapping)
{
    var result = new List<TResult>();
    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        result.Add(mapping.Map(s));
    }
    return result;
}

public abstract class Mapping<T, TResult>
{
    public abstract TResult Map(T t);
}
```

In statically typed functional programming languages like Haskell, generics are often called *parametric polymorphism*. That's a different kind of polymorphism.